Should some question titles be renamed after the question is resolved?
Some questions are along the lines of: "What does X mean in the sentence YYYYYYYXY"
Should we have a policy of renaming the question, after it has an accepted answer, so the title is more like. "X as a {insert grammatical role here}"
This will probably be better for indexing on google etc., and make the question more transparent for people browsing questions.

No, editing the title isn't necessary.
Titles should summarize the question. "What does X mean" is a more natural question that someone may be looking for. 
Leave the answer ("X is a ...") in the answers. They are indexed by Google as well, so when someone is searching for the same question, you'll get the best of both worlds and have a fully searchable question/answer pair.
